# "The given path's format is not supported"

Tags: c#

This is my first question and english is not my first language so please be comprehensive with me.

Basicaly my program save data in a .js file. I use SaveFileDialog method to set the path and use .FileName to set the... well file name. Here's how I do it

```
private void parcourir_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SaveFileDialog exportJSFile = new SaveFileDialog();

    // Getting year, month and day of the day to generate the file name
    DateTime date = DateTime.Today;

    exportJSFile.FileName = date.Year + "_" + date.Month + "_" + date.Day + "_ct.js";
    if (exportJSFile.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        this.JSfilePath.Text = exportJSFile.FileName;
    }
}
```

Then I use the StreamWriter to write data in my file

```
// Writing the first block (header) of data into the .js file
System.IO.StreamWriter objWriterFirstBlock;
objWriterFirstBlock = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@JSfilePath.ToString());
objWriterFirstBlock.Write(firstBlock);
objWriterFirstBlock.Close();
```

When I debug it, I get the above error message coming from this line:

```
objWriterFirstBlock = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@JSfilePath.ToString());
```

I tried the same command without the @, same result. When I use the dialog box to set the path name, the path is displayed in a textbox and it seems right. When I chek the value of JSfilePath.ToString() in the debugger, it shows a path like:

```
@JSfilePath = {Text = "C:\\Users\\admin\\Documents\\2014_3_5_ct.js"}
```

Can someone tell me what's wrong

Comment: `@` in front of an identifier escapes the indentifier, not its contents. This is only usefull if an identifier defined in a library created in another programming language happens to be a keyword in C#. `@if = "hello";` assuming that the variable `if` is a string.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming that `JSfilePath` is a `TextBox`, it appears that you are using the `ToString()` method on the `TextBox` itself, which will not return what you are looking for.

If you change it to `JSfilePath.Text` this should fix it for you:

```
objWriterFirstBlock = new System.IO.StreamWriter(JSfilePath.Text);
```

Comment: Yes, a `textbox.ToString()` will return something like `"System.Windows.Forms.TextBox, Text: xyz"`.